# Git, IntelliJ & Atom combination

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, atom-editor

I'm learning git in preparation of a new role that I'll soon be starting. Previously I've only used shoddy VCS systems and shoddier IDE's, I'm a little overwhelmed by the options available to me :)

For the tutorials I've been using Atom text editor and Git from terminal.  Both are working fine for the examples but I began wondering where IntelliJ fits into this.  It clearly has Git integration and support so would using the IDE built in features negate the use of Atom?

I have a local repo in folder x, if I then clone this repo using IDEA and set the parent directory to be in my DevWorkspace I lose the .git files and tracking.  If I clone and set the working directory to be folder x I'm worried that that would be going against the grain.

Trying to associate this with a real world example, I'd imagine a network repo that I'd clone, make local changes and then add / commit.  But where does Atom/intelliJ come into this?

If I use the command line to clone then does IDEA simply open the files in that project?  Atom is a useful editor but I suspect it may be redundant if the IDE is used properly and efficiently, can anyone advise?

Many thanks.

Comment: Depending on what you want, it's actually possible to transform Atom into an IDE, with the help of useful packages. Here is an example post that describes how to beef up the default git integration in atom. azizsaboor.wordpress.com/2015/12/22/git-integration-in-atom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, Atom is an editor, IntelliJ is an IDE. This leads to the usual pros and cons (like features vs simplicity/performance) in any IDE/editor war, which is highly subjective and hence not a topic for SO.

If you already have a local repo, you don't really need to clone it to import it into IntelliJ (unless that's your workflow). Just use `File > New > Project from Existing Sources` (IDEA 14.1.3+, it may differ in older versions) to create a project in your local repository. IntelliJ will automatically detect a Git repository and show you a confirmation popup. You can either confirm it or set  the root later in `Settings > Version Control`. This will tell IntelliJ to enable Git integration for your project. Now you can use many Git actions right from your IDE, under `VCS` and `VCS > Git`. You can also see your repository tree by selecting `Version Control` tab in the bottom panel or pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd>.

For full Git integration documentation check the IntelliJ IDEA Web Help for [Git](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/using-git-integration.html) and [Version Control](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/version-control-with-intellij-idea.html).

Regarding your real world example, you can clone any repository (local or remote) by selecting `File > Project from Version Control > Git/Github` (again, it might differ in IDEA < 14.1.3). IntelliJ will offer to create a new project for this repository. This is equal to clone a repository using Git in command line and creating a project from existing sources as described earlier.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering and adding some clarity.  Using the IDE does have some advantages it seems, the diff is especially nice. :)
There is something that I can't find which seems to be built in to Atom and thats the indicators of a status.  The filename will change colour and display an indicator in the gutter if/when I make changes.  Is there something similar in the IDE?  An 'at a glance' oh I've changed this file, it's been added etc - excluding the changes / log

Comment: IntelliJ highlights both files (in the project tree) and lines (on the left gutter) if something is changed/added/removed. The gutter indicator is especially useful, because you can diff or revert changes just for those lines. More info in the [Web Help](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/using-change-markers-to-view-and-navigate-through-changes-in-the-editor.html).

Comment: I'm a fool!  :)  I still had the file selected so it didn't change colour. :(  Thanks you again for your help. And wow, i see what you mean about the gutter, that's nice!